# Selected Faces show up lighter orange to normal

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

[image]When In edit mode and I press 'A' to select everything some of the faces on my mesh show up a lighter colored orange. This has caused a problem to when I import my mesh as an FBX into UE4 the faces are deleted.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have some normals flipped, with everything selected in edit mode hit CTRL+N and see if that helps.

Comment: All the faces effected are facing the same direction as the other faces (Thanks for fast reply's)

Comment: Im not sure, make sure you dont accidentally have duplicated geometry maybe you have extra faces under the the darker orange selection. I am just guessing, can you upload your blend file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4377" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4377/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your problem

You just need to go into edit mode and select all then on the left tool panel ("T") you need to remove doubles. Looks like you had extra vertices that are not needed. I think this is causing problems with your FBX export.

After you remove doubles you will see at the top a few hundred got removed and the shading got fixed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, That has fixed my issue thanks

Comment: Im glad please mark the answer as accepted so it may help others and get me my points lol